# setInterval and clearInterval with the same button?

Tags: javascript, html

I have looked around various set/clearInterval questions on here but none of them seem to pertain to exactly what im trying to do.

I have a simple application that shows a div that turns different colors like a strobe light when a button is clicked. I want the colors to start changing when a button is clicked, and stop changing when the button is clicked again.

I am stumped trying to figure out how I can make the interval clear based on what the buttons inner html is when it is clicked. Am I even on the right track here? Thanks!

```
<div id="party" width="200px" height="200px"></div>
<button id="btn" type="button" onclick="setInterval(function(){changeColor();}, 460)">
        Party On!</button>

<script>

var box = document.getElementById("box");

function changeColor() {

if (document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML == "Party On!") {
    document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML - "Party Off"
}

if (box.style.backgroundColor == "red") {
    box.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}

else if (box.style.backgroundColor == "blue") {
    box.style.backgroundColor = "green";

}

else if (box.style.backgroundColor == "green") {
    box.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";

}

else if (box.style.backgroundColor == "yellow") {
    box.style.backgroundColor = "red";

}

if (document.getElementById("button").innerHTML == "Party Off" {
    // Code to clear interval gos here?
}

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with:

```
<button id="btn" type="button" onclick="toggleInterval()">Party On!</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
var intervalId;
function toggleInterval() {
  if (!intervalId) {
    intervalId = setInterval(function(){changeColor();}, 460);
  } else {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    intervalId = null;
  }
}


// ...
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qGL8s/1/

Comment: @hsz Awesome. This is the functionality I was looking for. However when you change the text of the button back to 'Party On' you forgot the '!', which makes it so the text never changes back after the first click.